# Remove public from the subfolder of laravel in local and live

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

Here is my Directory Structure

```
localhost/project or livehost/project
-app
-bootstrap
-public
-vendor
```

Where i have `/project` as a folder inside the htdocs.

Now i am accessing the project by

```
localhost/project/public/
localhost/project/public/blog  // for submenu
```

How can i remove the `/project/public/` and use only the `localhost/project` and `localhost/project/blog`

And if move to live i will be having the project folder as main so How can i have the .htaccess for the localhost (which is inside the  project folder) and live (which will be in the root)

Here is the .htaccess i had for the the live (where the files will be on the live)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename the server.php in the your Laravel root folder to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder. -- Thats it !! :)

Comment: the easiest and best way so far.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server (you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2) if you don't know how to do). If it's already enabled but URL rewrite seems to not work, you can refer to "pretty URL" chapter of Laravel's documentation : http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#pretty-urls